# Rails: restful resource routing with action_controller_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, restful-url

I am putting a randomize def in my controller and would like to access it with a restful route. The route should be accessed with the following:

```
<%= link_to "Randomize", random_reader_path %>
```

But I cannot figure out how to get this route to appear in rake routes or configure it correctly in my routes.rb file.

The random method will do the same thing as index only provide a random page content @variable

Currently I have my reader Controller as

```
resources :reader
```

in my routes.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add more RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)!

```
resources :reader do
  get 'random', on: :collection
end
```

The route will be `random_readers_path`, though.

Comment: (I used the delicious Ruby 1.9 hash syntax; if you’re on tragic 1.8, you’ll have to write `get 'random', :on => :collection`.)

Comment: sadly I still have undefined local variable or method `random_readers_path' even after adding your exact code to my routes. (modified resources :reader, didn't add a new one ;) ) thanks for the link though

Comment: by adding   resources :readers do
    collection do
      get 'random'
    end
  end I get the path to work but when I click the link, I get uninitialized constant ReadersController

Comment: Oh, oops. It’s traditional to use plural names on a `resources` call, I didn’t even grasp that you’re using `reader`. Any reason for that? It’ll be called `random_reader_index` because of that (no way to make `reader` any more singular), I think; you can run `rake routes` on the command line to see all the named routes.